# Integrating mvc.jquery.datatables and T4MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, t4mvc, datatables-1.10

I'm using [mvc.jquery.datatables](https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables) with Asp.Net MVC 4 and [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)

It works fine and as expected.

When I introduce [T4 MVC](https://t4mvc.codeplex.com) to replace MVC magic strings, T4 MVC does not like the return type that mvc.jquery.datatables wants me to use in my Ajax action method.

The return type is:

```
DataTablesResult<MyType>
```

T4 MVC does not like this and responds with the error:

> The type 'Mvc.JQuery.Datatables.DataTablesResult `<TSource>` ' has no constructors defined    T4MVC.cs

So, how can I get T4 MVC and mvc.jquery.datatables to play ball, and at worst, can I get T4 MVC to ignore that one action?

Comment: Hi I need to consider a solution for this problem as well. I would be interested to know how you chose to resolve this in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a great way to ignore specific actions, though it would make sense to add that.

I think that if you were to add a `[Obsolete]` attribute on it, it would get ignored, though clearly that's a hack. If you look in `ProcessControllerActionMethods` in t4mvc.tt, you'll see the various conditions that cause actions to get ignored.

If you want to tackle creating a new attribute to ignore actions, we can take this to https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/. Or potentially it can be smarter and auto detect this situation.